# Android location loop

Tags: android, location

I'm using the following code to get the users location:

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
  //=========================================== On Create ========================================
  @
  Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //======================================= Location =========================================
    LocationManager mlocManager =
      (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
  }
}
```

```js
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {@
  Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    String Text = "My current location is: " +
      "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() +
      "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      Text,
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }@
  Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Gps Disabled",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }@
  Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Gps Enabled",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }@
  Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

When I run the app, it goes into an endless loop of displaying me the location of the user. How can I make it show location only once with a click of a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited the code below to use either GPS or Network location.

Also use these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is a very simple case, a UI with just a `Button` and a `TextView`.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button;
TextView locText;
double lat;
double lon;
Location loc;
LocationManager mlocManager;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);

    locText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mlocManager =
            (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    //mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE); //Try this instead
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    provider = mlocManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    if (provider != null) {
        loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        lat = loc.getLatitude();
        lon = loc.getLongitude();
    }

    locText.setText(lat + " " + lon);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (provider != null) {
                loc = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                lat = loc.getLatitude();
                lon = loc.getLongitude();
            }

            locText.setText(lat + " " + lon);
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Refresh Location"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonGo"
            android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually I am using AsyncTask :D because I'm making a weather app that waits for the data to load and displays the current weather. I've trimmed the code above and added to my PreExecute with Async, so I'm guessing everytime Async is called it will get the location. However its not working as I expected. If I run the app with location off it sets the lon and lat as 0,0. How do I fix this?

Comment: There's no way to get a location from GPS with the Location Mode set to off.  You may want to use `getLastKnownLocation()` in conjunction with registering a listener.  Just be sure to use reasonable values when registering your listener, so that you aren't constantly using the GPS radio.  Also, you may want to use Network location if GPS isn't available, which uses less battery as well.

Comment: If I request location update then I have to use a register another class, In my case above it was  

`LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();`

Is there any workaround to it?

Comment: I just updated the answer, take a look.  This approach will make it work if the GPS radio is off, but Google Location Services (aka Network location) is enabled, i.e. Battery Saving mode on some phones.  This is really the best you can do, use any location data that's available.  If Location mode is set to off, there's nothing you can do to get the location.  In that case, you should just prompt the user to enable Location Services from your app.

Comment: I understand that but I do not wish to create another class. The mlockListener as you pointed out needs the class, how do I create it by its own. I'm confused, not sure if you understand me.

Comment: Ok, I see.  Take a look at the updated `MainActivity` code, it doesn't require a listener, and it can use either GPS or Network location.

Comment: Alright it works as long as I use (GPS and networks), If I use either (Networks Only) or (GPS only), it sets the lon, lat to 0. Also I want to add that I'm using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> `instead of fine location, not sure how that makes a difference in what I'm doing.

Comment: If that's the permission you're using, try using `Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE`.  See the last edit in the answer.  I was able to get location data with it set to Network only with this code, but I had more permissions set.

Comment: It works most of the time but after I switch between the settings (Location and Network), (Network), (Location) and I open the app again the long and lat have no values, (not even 0,0). My app actually updates everything onResume.